# How to make button sticky to the bottom inside ScrollView in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, sticky-footer, react-native-scrollview

As per the solution given on other answers, to place the sticky content outside the scrollview. But when I am placing sticky button outide the scrollview and when the soft keyboard popsup, the sticky button pops-up to the top of content as it is not inside scrollView. Ideally button should stick to the bottom even after keyboard pops-up i.e. it should be behind the keyboard. Please check video in the attached URL.

https://filebin.net/e7ek1zkt9840f9lw

Related snack is:

https://snack.expo.io/qtTC4tvTE

Comment: Add your code to help to you otherwise how can we answer ?

Comment: I have created a snack for this issue: https://snack.expo.io/qtTC4tvTE

Answer (score 0):

You can use stickyHeaderIndices props to ScrollView. consider your structure is as follows:

```
     <ScrollView> 
       <View><Text>This is header</Text></View>
       <View><Text>This is body</Text></View>
       <View><Text>This is footer</Text></View>
     </ScrollView>
```

and if you want to make your footer part sticky then simply put stickyHeaderIndices={[2]} inside scrollview.

```
      <ScrollView stickyHeaderIndices={[2]}> 
       <View><Text>This is header</Text></View>
       <View><Text>This is body</Text></View>
       <View><Text>This is footer</Text></View>
     </ScrollView>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. This makes content sticky during scrolling and prevent the StickyHeaderIndices to go out of the screen.